# searching concat value

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem in searching concat values,
 
is there any ways using "mysql query" or "php algorithm" ??
my idea is,, i have four column to combine (concate) as ID field and NAME field.
using this two field, actualy i have an input text to use for searching this two field (ID and NAME) 
i have query like this but this doesn't work (because of this line: **id   like '%$search%'**)

```
select
      concat(
         id_1, '.',
         id_2, '.',
         id_3, '.',
         id_4
      ) 
      as id,
      name

    from
      employee

    where
           id   like '%$search%'
      or   name like '%$search%'
```

Comment: Do you get an error or no results?

Comment: @gbn,, yes i have error message: #1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'.. i think you are right, the "id" hasn't been prepared yet when the WHERE clause is applied. i'm very newbie in mysql query :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"id" hasn't been prepared yet when the WHERE clause is applied

So use a derived table:

```
select
    id, name
FROM
    (
    select
      concat(
         id_1, '.',
         id_2, '.',
         id_3, '.',
         id_4
      ) 
      as id,
      name
    from
      employee
    ) as intermediate
    where
           id   like '%$search%'
      or   name like '%$search%'
```

or repeat the expression

```
select
  concat(
     id_1, '.',
     id_2, '.',
     id_3, '.',
     id_4
  ) 
  as id,
  name
from
  employee
where
  concat(
     id_1, '.',
     id_2, '.',
     id_3, '.',
     id_4
  ) like '%$search%'
  or   name like '%$search%'
```

Comment: +1 MySQL does also allow column aliases to be referenced in `having` but not `where`